# All of the Boards

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Problem source: https://oj.vnoi.info/problem/backtrack_j

We have these two shapes:

```
#.
##
```

and

```
.#
##
```

Let's call the first shape the L and the second shape the flipped L.

On a 4x4 board, there are 16 cells. Each cell can be either free or occupied. In all the illustrations, `#` represents an occupied cell and `.` represents a free cell.

Your job is to print **all 4x4 boards** that can be completely filled using the L shape and the flipped L shape. You are not allowed to rotate or flip the shapes, but you can put them anywhere you want as long as the shape isn't clashing with existing occupied cells. **You are allowed to represent the boards in any reasonable format and print them in any order.**

Here is an example of a board that can be filled:

```
.##.
....
.##.
....
```

We can perform these steps to fill the whole board.

Step 1: Fill an L at the top left corner

```
###.
##..
.##.
....
```

Step 2: Fill a flipped L at the top right corner

```
####
####
.##.
....
```

Step 3: Fill an L at the bottom left corner

```
####
####
###.
##..
```

Step 4: Fill a flipped L at the bottom right corner

```
####
####
####
####
```

Here is an example of a board that can't be filled:

```
#...
....
....
....
```

No matter how hard you try, it's just impossible to fill the board.

Sample output:

```
###.
#...
....
....

##.#
#...
....
....

#.##
...#
....
....

.###
...#
....
....

####
##.#
....
....

####
#.##
....
....

#.#.
....
#.#.
....

.##.
....
#.#.
....

#..#
....
#.#.
....

.#.#
....
#.#.
....

###.
##..
#.#.
....

##.#
##..
#.#.
....

##.#
#..#
#.#.
....

#.##
#..#
#.#.
....

#.##
..##
#.#.
....

.###
..##
#.#.
....

####
####
#.#.
....

#.#.
....
.##.
....

.##.
....
.##.
....

#..#
....
.##.
....

.#.#
....
.##.
....

###.
##..
.##.
....

##.#
##..
.##.
....

##.#
#..#
.##.
....

#.##
#..#
.##.
....

#.##
..##
.##.
....

.###
..##
.##.
....

####
####
.##.
....

#.#.
....
#..#
....

.##.
....
#..#
....

#..#
....
#..#
....

.#.#
....
#..#
....

###.
##..
#..#
....

##.#
##..
#..#
....

##.#
#..#
#..#
....

#.##
#..#
#..#
....

#.##
..##
#..#
....

.###
..##
#..#
....

####
####
#..#
....

#.#.
....
.#.#
....

.##.
....
.#.#
....

#..#
....
.#.#
....

.#.#
....
.#.#
....

###.
##..
.#.#
....

##.#
##..
.#.#
....

##.#
#..#
.#.#
....

#.##
#..#
.#.#
....

#.##
..##
.#.#
....

.###
..##
.#.#
....

####
####
.#.#
....

###.
#...
#...
##..

##.#
#...
#...
##..

#.##
...#
#...
##..

.###
...#
#...
##..

####
##.#
#...
##..

####
#.##
#...
##..

###.
#...
..#.
##..

##.#
#...
..#.
##..

###.
.#..
..#.
##..

##.#
.#..
..#.
##..

##.#
...#
..#.
##..

#.##
...#
..#.
##..

####
#.##
..#.
##..

####
.###
..#.
##..

#.#.
....
###.
##..

.##.
....
###.
##..

#..#
....
###.
##..

.#.#
....
###.
##..

###.
##..
###.
##..

##.#
##..
###.
##..

##.#
#..#
###.
##..

#.##
#..#
###.
##..

#.##
..##
###.
##..

.###
..##
###.
##..

####
####
###.
##..

###.
#...
...#
##..

##.#
#...
...#
##..

###.
.#..
...#
##..

##.#
.#..
...#
##..

##.#
...#
...#
##..

#.##
...#
...#
##..

####
#.##
...#
##..

####
.###
...#
##..

#.#.
....
##.#
##..

.##.
....
##.#
##..

#..#
....
##.#
##..

.#.#
....
##.#
##..

###.
##..
##.#
##..

##.#
##..
##.#
##..

##.#
#..#
##.#
##..

#.##
#..#
##.#
##..

#.##
..##
##.#
##..

.###
..##
##.#
##..

####
####
##.#
##..

##.#
#...
#...
#..#

#.##
#...
#...
#..#

#.##
..#.
#...
#..#

.###
..#.
#...
#..#

####
###.
#...
#..#

#.##
...#
#...
#..#

.###
...#
#...
#..#

####
##.#
#...
#..#

###.
#...
...#
#..#

##.#
#...
...#
#..#

###.
.#..
...#
#..#

##.#
.#..
...#
#..#

##.#
...#
...#
#..#

#.##
...#
...#
#..#

####
#.##
...#
#..#

####
.###
...#
#..#

#.#.
....
##.#
#..#

.##.
....
##.#
#..#

#..#
....
##.#
#..#

.#.#
....
##.#
#..#

###.
##..
##.#
#..#

##.#
##..
##.#
#..#

##.#
#..#
##.#
#..#

#.##
#..#
##.#
#..#

#.##
..##
##.#
#..#

.###
..##
##.#
#..#

####
####
##.#
#..#

#.#.
....
#.##
#..#

.##.
....
#.##
#..#

#..#
....
#.##
#..#

.#.#
....
#.##
#..#

###.
##..
#.##
#..#

##.#
##..
#.##
#..#

##.#
#..#
#.##
#..#

#.##
#..#
#.##
#..#

#.##
..##
#.##
#..#

.###
..##
#.##
#..#

####
####
#.##
#..#

##.#
#...
#...
..##

#.##
#...
#...
..##

#.##
..#.
#...
..##

.###
..#.
#...
..##

####
###.
#...
..##

#.##
...#
#...
..##

.###
...#
#...
..##

####
##.#
#...
..##

##.#
#...
.#..
..##

#.##
#...
.#..
..##

#.##
..#.
.#..
..##

.###
..#.
.#..
..##

####
###.
.#..
..##

#.##
...#
.#..
..##

.###
...#
.#..
..##

####
##.#
.#..
..##

###.
#...
...#
..##

##.#
#...
...#
..##

#.##
...#
...#
..##

.###
...#
...#
..##

####
##.#
...#
..##

####
#.##
...#
..##

#.#.
....
#.##
..##

.##.
....
#.##
..##

#..#
....
#.##
..##

.#.#
....
#.##
..##

###.
##..
#.##
..##

##.#
##..
#.##
..##

##.#
#..#
#.##
..##

#.##
#..#
#.##
..##

#.##
..##
#.##
..##

.###
..##
#.##
..##

####
####
#.##
..##

#.#.
....
.###
..##

.##.
....
.###
..##

#..#
....
.###
..##

.#.#
....
.###
..##

###.
##..
.###
..##

##.#
##..
.###
..##

##.#
#..#
.###
..##

#.##
#..#
.###
..##

#.##
..##
.###
..##

.###
..##
.###
..##

####
####
.###
..##

##.#
....
....
####

#.##
....
....
####

####
#.#.
....
####

####
.##.
....
####

####
#..#
....
####

####
.#.#
....
####

##.#
#...
##..
####

#.##
#...
##..
####

#.##
..#.
##..
####

.###
..#.
##..
####

####
###.
##..
####

#.##
...#
##..
####

.###
...#
##..
####

####
##.#
##..
####

###.
#...
#..#
####

##.#
#...
#..#
####

#.##
...#
#..#
####

.###
...#
#..#
####

####
##.#
#..#
####

####
#.##
#..#
####

###.
#...
..##
####

##.#
#...
..##
####

###.
.#..
..##
####

##.#
.#..
..##
####

##.#
...#
..##
####

#.##
...#
..##
####

####
#.##
..##
####

####
.###
..##
####

#.#.
....
####
####

.##.
....
####
####

#..#
....
####
####

.#.#
....
####
####

###.
##..
####
####

##.#
##..
####
####

##.#
#..#
####
####

#.##
#..#
####
####

#.##
..##
####
####

.###
..##
####
####

####
####
####
####
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I've got 1234 valid forms, is it right?

Comment: No, only 215 sorry

Comment: Can we output the same board more than once?

Comment: I'm sorry but all the boards must be unique. Otherwise your output could be very large and that makes it hard for me to check your submission for correctness.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/194473/58563)

Comment: @HuỳnhTrầnKhanh Thank you, I have a nice math day (^_^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 28 bytes

```
2r↕1:ÐÐ3r~ᵑᵐç3r~ᵑçaᵐᶜ{0*}∑2<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6Fjf1jIoetU01tDo84fAE46K6h1snPtw64fByCPPw8kQg7-G2OdUGWrWPOiYa2SwpTkouhuqFmQEA)

Outputs 215 4×4 matrices using `1`s for free and `0`s for occupied cells.

#### Explanation

```
2r↕1:ÐÐ3r~ᵑᵐç3r~ᵑçaᵐᶜ{0*}∑2<
2r↕1:ÐÐ                         Push [[0,1],[1,1]] or [[1,0],[1,1]]
       3r~ᵑᵐç                   Prepend 0, 1 or 2 zeros to each sublist
             3r~ᵑç              Prepend 0, 1 or 2 zeros to the list
                  a             Get all possible values as a list
                   ᵐᶜ{0*}       Optionally multiply each value by zero
                         ∑      Take the sum
                          2<    Check if all numbers in the result is less than 2
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 122 bytes (-2 thanks to @ovs)

```python
A=0,19,35
for d in(2,16)*2:A={x|y*d for x in A for y in A if 1>x&y*d}
for i in A:print(f"{i:019_b}_".translate(33*"#.\n"))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3qxxtDXQMLXWMTbnS8osUUhQy8zSMdAzNNLWMrBxtqytqKrVSFEAyFUAZBUcwsxLCzExTMLSrUAMqqAXrzQQLWxUUZeaVaKQpVWdaGRhaxifVxivplRQl5hXnJJakahgbaykp68XkKWlqQlywKbG4OLWoRCEnNU_DUdPW1sjQFCIBcyIA)

##### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org), 124 bytes (-1 thanks to @xnor)

```python
A={0,19,35}
for d in(2,16)*2:A={x|y*d for x in A for y in A if 1>x&y*d}
for i in A:print(f"{i:019_b}_".translate(33*"#.\n"))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3axxtqw10DC11jE1rudLyixRSFDLzNIx0DM00tYysgJIVNZVaKQogmQqgjIIjmFkJYWamKRjaVagBFUD0ZoKFrQqKMvNKNNKUqjOtDAwt45Nq45X0SooS84pzEktSNYyNtZSU9WLylDQ1IW7YlFhcnFpUopCTmqfhqGlra2RoCpGAORIA)

##### Previous [Python](https://www.python.org), 126 bytes

```python
A={0,19,35}
for d in(1,4)*2:A|={(x|y<<d)*(1>x&y<<d)for x in A for y in A}
for i in A:print(f"{i:019_b}_".translate(33*"#.\n"))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY36xxtqw10DC11jE1rudLyixRSFDLzNAx1TDS1jKwca2yrNSpqKm1sUjS1NAztKtTATJCyCqAyBUcFELMSzITozgSzrQqKMvNKNNKUqjOtDAwt45Nq45X0SooS84pzEktSNYyNtZSU9WLylDQ1Ia6AOgbmKAA)

Comment: It looks like you can save a byte by replacing the `<<`'s with multiplies

Comment: Now that you're not doing `|=` anymore, A can be a tuple initially

Comment: Since "you are allowed to present the board in any reasonable format", could you perhaps skip the translate step and do `f"{i:019_b}_".replace("_","\n")` instead for -3 bytes?

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>249</s> <s>230</s> <s>224</s> 210 bytes

```
(r={f=Table[1,{4},{4}]};p={e={1,1},{0,2},{2,0}};q=Flatten[Table[ArrayPad[k,{i,j}],{k,{{{1,0},e},{{0,1},e}}},{i,p},{j,p}],2];(a=#;r=Join[r,v=Select[a-#&/@q,AllTrue[#,(#>=0&),2]&]];Table[#0[e],{e,v}])&@f;Union@r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BSwMxEIV/TGDZhRGzi7cwkl48iIeC9RRyGOvUpqZpG2KphPz2dZYe5uPxmI93pLLnI5WwpfmGc5@x7nBDn5HdCPWpLeebOWNlrCOMUmiYhBPo1swFXyKVwsndnVXO9LemL/cDNcCheaiSqpi6AYsm9rik1paHs/Ag9DB50xMqk/H1FJLLcMV3jrwtjh5U92gvsIpxk3/ZKejVM@puEKfz3tyHlXYsYwzX5ofO7sxHCqdk8zCvc0jFvnH6Lnt7m/8B)

Recursive solution based on the next fact :
If given matrix is valid and we remove from it "L" or "anti-L", then the new matrix will be valid too.

All valid boards in a single picture:

[image]

Ungolfed version as explanation:

```
init = Table[1, {4}, {4}];
result = {init};
forms = {{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}};
pads = {{1, 1}, {0, 2}, {2, 0}};
patterns = 
  Flatten[Table[
    ArrayPad[k, {i, j}], {k, forms}, {i, pads}, {j, pads}], 2];
main[arr_] := 
  With[{nextValid = 
     Select[arr - # & /@ patterns, AllTrue[#, (# >= 0 &)] &, 2]},
   result = Join[result, nextValid];
   main[#] & /@ nextValid
   ];
main@init;
output = Union@result;
```

The longest part of code is a preparing of matrix patterns.
I'll try to golf it harder!
That's all. Add a some mad golfing, and can’t improve the algorithm anymore (

Comment: @LuisMendo, yes you are right! Should be fixed soon

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 159 bytes

A rather lenghty port of [loopy walt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259580/58563).

```javascript
f=(A=new Set([0,19,35]),d=2)=>(B=[...A])[99]?B.map(v=>(g=k=>k--?"#."[v>>k&1]+[`
`[k&3]]+g(k):'')(16)).join`
`:f(A,d^18,B.map(x=>B.map(y=>x&y*d||A.add(x|y*d))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRCoIwGIXve4owsH81RyZFBv9kvkKXY5E0FVttkmIGvrsNOlff@Q6cRzEU3f3dtH1knS7nuUIQaMvP8lL2IHc0TmlyUIRq3BPkkKNkjAlFZJqqLGevooXB@xoNchNFWbBigRw4N2GstvK2uEkTJkptazDkvF4TiI@EsIdrrN/OFQiqr/GJ/p9G5H/4Ih/D70ZPk2CF1jBOvhCf@e5s554le7oaKvDiBw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 152 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
r=[[[r,c]|r<-[0..3],c<-[0..3],notElem[r,c]l]|l<-concat<$>subsequences[[[r-1,c+t],[r,c],[r,c+1]]|r<-[1..3],c<-[0..2],t<-[0,1]],l==nub l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDsIgFEV3v6JDtz4a0RWcdPMPyBsoIZH4Sis8tv47WkyMy81J7sl52Pz0RLWGeV0Sd1fLdryHzIekjTEJHG5JCXMcxzOC@1Fc@EZ@bgLhRkq4JTrLqr/kMmX/Kj46n/eEkOAGRmhu20Hityr/qycE3gk@L5DWsUwdYZ1tiHpNIXKf6hs)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
56āδš<TÝ37SKδ+€`æε˜ÐÙQiX16Å0rǝ4ô,
```

Outputs as a list of matrices of 0s for `.` and 1s for `#`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9vc2FiaWX//zU2xIHOtMWhPFTDnTM3U0vOtCvigqxgw6bOtcucw5DDmVFpWDE2w4UwcsedNMO0LP///y0tbm8tbGF6eQ) or [try it online with pretty-printing footer](https://tio.run/##AVIArf9vc2FiaWX//zU2xIHOtMWhPFTDnTM3U0vOtCvigqxgw6bOtcucw5DDmVFpWDE2w4UwcsedNMO0/@KAni4jc8OoSsK7LMK2P///LS1uby1sYXp5). (Pretty slow, so only outputs about 175 of them before timing out on TIO.)

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Push the 0-based indices of the two shapes at every possible position on the (flattened) 4x4 board:

```python
56āδš<            # Push the indices of the two L-shapes in the top-left corner of the
                  # (flattened) board:
56                #  Push 56
  ā               #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping): [1,2]
   δ              #  Apply double-vectorized:
    š             #   Prepend: [[1,5,6],[2,5,6]]
     <            #  Decrease each inner value by 1: [[0,4,5],[1,4,5]]
TÝ37SKδ+€`        # Combine it with every position these 2x2-shapes can be on the 4x4
                  # board:
TÝ                #  Push a list in the range [0,10]
  37SK            #  Remove the 3 and 7: [0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10]
δ                 #  Apply double-vectorized
 +                #   Add the values together
  €`              #  Flatten it one level down
```

[Try just step 1 online.](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//zU2xIHOtMWhPFTDnTM3U0vOtCvigqxg//8)

Step 2: Get all possible 0..length combinations of these possible shape-positions, and check if they can be combined without overlapping indices:

```python
æ                 # Get the powerset of this list of lists shape-indices
 ε                # Foreach over each inner list:
  ˜               #  Flatten it to a single list of indices
   ÐÙQ            #  Check if all indices are unique:
   Ð              #   Triplicate the list of indices
    Ù             #   Uniquify the top copy
     Q            #   Check if the top two lists are still the same
```

[Try just the first two steps online.](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//zU2xIHOtMWhPFTDnTM3U0vOtCvigqxgw6bOtcucw5DDmVH//w)

Step 3: For each valid list of indices, create the board-matrix and output it:

```python
      i           #  If the earlier check is truthy:
       X          #   Push a 1
        16Å0      #   Push a list of 16 0s
            r     #   Reverse the stack from indices,1,16x0 to 16x0,1,indices
                  #   (where the indices are from the triplcate of step 2)
             ǝ    #   Insert a 1 into the list of 16 0s at the given indices
              4ô  #   Split the list into parts of size 4
                , #   Pop and output this 4x4 matrix with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 47 bytes

```
⊞υ⁵⁴¹²⁰⁰Ｆ¹³Ｆ×Ｘ²ι⟦³⁵¦⁶⁷⟧ＦυＦ¬＆λκ⊞υ⁺λκＥυＥ⪪⍘ι²¦⁵Φλξ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5PC4JAEMXvfYo5zsIGqWiEp4S6CYLdosNSlkOb2v7Jvv02mQ083sBvZt6cW2XOvdIhVN626CVEqyTKskTki2tvAKONgKk50KOxWPVjYzCWQELCMUklZOuTmEf87LunV9piQW4k22y7C2oJd/GVgH9OSZ23P8BZlaHOYamGCbHVgyaHhbJN7ZjdkCTEfCJl7Uk7/oJ334IrDyEsX/oD) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs 215 4×4 grids using `1`s for free and `0`s for occupied cells. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⁵⁴¹²⁰⁰
```

Start with a completely occupied grid. `541200` is `10000100001000010000` in binary, where the `0`s are occupied cells and the `1`s are separators; the grid is obtained by splitting the bits into rows of `5` and then deleting the first column.

```
Ｆ¹³
```

Loop over all valid and some invalid (`3`, `4`, `8` and `9`) shape positions. (Invalid shape positions intersect the separators thus preventing shapes from being removed at those positions.)

```
Ｆ×Ｘ²ι⟦³⁵¦⁶⁷⟧
```

Loop over the bit patterns that represent the two `L` shapes at that position.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over the existing boards.

```
Ｆ¬＆λκ⊞υ⁺λκ
```

If the shape can be removed then add the new board.

```
ＥυＥ⪪⍘ι²¦⁵Φλξ
```

Output the discovered boards.